# Solr Arabic search not working unless words are neighbors

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tokenize

So far my solr deployment for a set of Arabic data I have is working great. The stemming and normalization are all quite fantastic.

The problem now is that the arabic search does not work UNLESS the words all form a contiguous phase. For example, let's say the following phrase:

اسْمُهُ دَاوُدُ بْنُ أَبِي

works just fine and gives me the desired data. However, if I search:

اسْمُهُ دَاوُدُ أَبِي

Then I get 0 results. Notice the second line is merely missing one of the words from the line above.

I should be able to get results even if the words don't appear next to each other in the text itself.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. My schema is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_arabic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>    
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="arabic_stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>    
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: How are you querying ? what request hanlder are you using ? what query parser are you using ? can you post you solr configuration as well ?

Comment: I figured out the problem here. We were not specifying the correct column type in the query to Solr. My apologies for this!

Answer (score 0):

try use the dismax instead of solr normal boolean query it gives u phrases search and cross fields search, because u do phrases query.

example:

q=أحمد+فنان+مجتهد&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=title_ar+title_en+title&mm=70%25&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true

as you will see in the response i get a match but not exact match, check the expression above you will see mm("minimum match") is setted to 70% means that 70% of the phrase should be match. for more info see(https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax)
the result to the above query is :

{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "lowercaseOperators": "true",
      "mm": "70%",
      "indent": "true",
      "uf": "title_ar title_en title",
      "q": "أحمد فنان مجتهد",
      "qf": "title_ar title_en title",
      "_": "1393151025195",
      "stopwords": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "defType": "edismax"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": [
          "ahmad is popular artist"
        ],
        "title_en": [
          "ahmad is popular artist"
        ],
        "title_ar": [
          "أحمد فنان مشهور"
        ],
        "*version*": 1460824159992938500
      }
    ]
  }
}